# Minor stuff on the profile page in iPad app

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, ipad

1. The listing of the communities in the Top Communities pane on the profile page is not based entirely on reputation or other activity. See below screen shots for clarification. Theoretical Computer Science has priority over for example Linguistics, on which I have more reputation and badges. This order is not the same as in the left-most pane where the icons of the communities are. The screen shot from the web version is included at the bottom for reference.
2. In my opinion, the blue color should be reserved for clickable/tappable links. The color choice for the headings should be different (in the web version they are black).
3. Make the capitalization of the headings consistent; Top Communities, but Top tags.

   ```
    Version: 1.1.0.125    
    Platform: Ipad 3, iOS 7.1.2
   ```

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. I have corrected the ordering of the Top Communities to correctly sort by descending reputation. This was wrong because we were only taking into consideration the first 5 accounts.
2. Good point. I've updated some of the colors to make it easier to distinguish out what's tappable. Non-tappable text is no longer blue.
3. Capitalized!

You should see these changes in version **1.1.0.128**. Here's what it will look like:

[image]